# Java Calendar get Xº day of the week of month

Tags: java, weekday

I'm need to do a method that returns the position of actual day in the next month.

```
for today (20/12/2016)
  I need to call this method whit today date
  The return given must to be (17/01/2016)
  This method must return the third Tuesday of the next month
  Is the 4 week of this month, but I need the Third Tuesday.
```

I try to use **Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK** but I can't get the third, I always get the fourth.

Some thing like this:

```
public static Date getNextMonthDayOfWeel(Date d) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);

    int week = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    //// this block
    if(!firstWeekOfMonthHad(day)){
        week++;
    }
    //// this block

    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);

    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, week);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);

    return c.getTime();
}
```

How can I get if the first week of the month have the specific day of the week?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and provide a [mcve]

Comment: So, is it the 3rd Tuesday or he X Monday.  These are different dates.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Java 8 or later, it is as simple as:

```
LocalDate.now()
.plusMonths(1)
.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY))
.plusWeeks(3);
```

Comment: My project is in java 7 =/

Comment: Ok, then joda-time can do the same thing if you add as a dependency

Comment: @gFontaniva Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project. The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes (or backport).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )                         // Get current date in this particular time zone.
    .plusMonths( 1 )                                                 // Move to equivalent date in the month after.
    .with( 
        TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth​( 3 , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY )  // Move to the ordinal number occurrence of a day-of-week within this month.
    )
```

## Details

You seem to be asking for the third Tuesday of next month.

The [Answer by Mellgren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41243791/642706) is good, but here's a variation on that idea using a more appropriate `TemporalAdjuster`.

### Avoid legacy classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Move to the next month.

```
LocalDate monthLater = today.plusMonths( 1 );
```

### `TemporalAdjuster`

To move to the third Tuesday of the month, use an implementation of [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

For an ordinal day-of-week within a month like “Third Tuesday of the month” or “First Thursday of the month”, Java offers a specific adjuster: [`TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth-int-java.time.DayOfWeek-). Pass the ordinal number such as `3` for “third”, and a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object constant such as `DayOfWeek.TUESDAY`.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 3 , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY );  // Pass ordinal number and `DayOfWeek`. 
LocalDate thirdTuesdayOfNextMonth = monthLater.with( ta );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "today is " + today + " in zone " + z );
System.out.println( "Third Tuesday of next month is " + thirdTuesdayOfNextMonth );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qI6P0g).

> Today is 2018-01-20 in zone America/Montreal
>
> Third Tuesday of next month is 2018-02-20

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).